# easy-sketch.js is supporting for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, ios, html5-canvas, sketch-3, sketching

I have used easy-sketch.js for canvas drawing. I developed for both WEB and IOS. now I confused whether its working in IOS? because touch drawing is not working in easy-sketch?
can anyone suggest me the solution.